# Bug na tradução de medalhas de revisão

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Nas medalhadas "Analista" e "Administrador" a tradução está incorreta:

[image: analista,administrador]

> analisar N mais

Sugiro que seja atualizado para

> analisar N ou mais

<sub>Nota: Até mesmo em inglês o texto está estranho.</sub>

Comment: Eu acho que seria melhor "analisar mais N" (para ganhar a medalha).